# How to generate text from dropdownbox while clicking

Tags: .net, drop-down-menu

for example dropdown box contain three things Simon,Jaison,Rahul..if you click Jaison
will generate jaison as a text,,or Simon will generate Simon as a text

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to change some label in response to a change in which item is selected in a drop-down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but if you're trying to get a string from the currently selected item (when the selection changes), then...

Handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedText = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    // Do whatever you want to do with it, for example...
    label1.Text = selectedText;
}
```